# Finding the newest file in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I am a complete novice in batch programming but have found some great scripts in here that I tried modifying. I need the info on the last file modified in a directory. The script below gives me a file with info about file name and modification time. It searches through subdirectories too but seems to get stuck in a subdirectory instead of finding the newer file in the parent directory. I am not sure what could be wrong (as I only partly understand the code). Any suggestions from you smart guys in here?

Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off

setlocal

set srcDir=C:\Test

set lastmod=

pushd "%srcDir%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *. * /b /od /s /a-d 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a

if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof

for /d %%a in ("%lastmod%") do echo "%lastmod%", Modified date: %%~ta>"C:\Test\Details.txt"
```

Comment: Do you want it to search in subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

This uses robocopy so it will only work on windows Vista and later. For it to work on XP you will need to get a copy of `robocopy` from a later OS or from resource kit.

No copy operation will really be made, but it will allow to retrieve a recursive file list with an adequated file stamp that can be sorted to find latest file.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%cd%"

    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in (
        'robocopy "%folder%" "%folder%" "*" /s /is /nocopy /nc /ns /ts /fp /np /ndl /njh /njs /xjd /r:0 /w:0 /l ^| sort /r '
    ) do ( set "latest=%%b" & goto :done )
    :done

    for %%f in ("%latest%") do echo(%%~tf %%~ff
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And yes, it should also include subdirectories. I tried filling in the directories, but couldn't get it to work. The error message I get is 'sort: open failed: /r: No such file or directory'. Should I have filled in a directory somewhere there or is the /r switch wrong?

Comment: @user3297825, it include subdirectories (see the `/s` switch of robocopy). Sort command is not reading any file. What it has to do is read and sort in reverse order (the `/r` switch) the data comming from robocopy over the pipe (`^|`). As is, it works for the current directory and below.

Comment: +1 That is marvelous.  Robocopy uses `UTC time` in the process, and `sorts the date` for you.  The fact that a whole tree can be processed makes it potentially very useful.